# How to combine this css?

Tags: css, stylesheet

```
.box_content ::selection {
 background:#CCCC33; /* Safari */
}
.box_content ::-moz-selection {
 background:#CCCC33; /* Firefox */
}
```

Anyone know if I can combine those like this?

```
.box_content ::selection .box_content ::-moz-selection {
 background:#CCCC33;
}
```

Or maybe like:

```
.box_content ::selection, .box_content ::-moz-selection {
 background:#CCCC33;
}
```

Comment: you've written the correct code in your question, but you never actually tried it out?

Comment: @Joe - Please don't leave questions open, go back and accept answers, it makes your questions much more appealing to would-be answerers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is correct. You can use a comma to separate css selection rules.

So given:

```
selector-rule1, selector-rule2 {
    style-x;
    style-y;
}
```

This will apply `style-x` & `style-y` to anything that matches **either** `selector-rule1` **or** `selector-rule2`.

---

Just to explain why your first example won't work, its because `spaces` imply ancestor-descendant relationships, so if you have:

```
selector-rule4 selector-rule4 {
    style-z;
}
```

Then `style-z` will be applied to anything that matches `selector-rule4` if it is also an an ancestor of something that matches `selector-rule3`.

[More info on selectors here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pattern-matching).

Answer (score 0):

Your second example should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

[You need to use a comma](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#grouping) to group the selectors:

```
.box_content ::selection, .box_content ::-moz-selection {
   background:#CCCC33;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example **can’t work** because a browser [has to ignore](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#rule-sets) the complete rule:

> When a user agent cannot parse the
>   selector (i.e., it is not valid CSS
>   2.1), it must ignore the selector and the following declaration block (if
>   any) as well.

Opera and Webkit can’t parse the Gecko proprietary selector and Gecko can’t parse the regular ::selection. So the rule will never be applied.